# How to use agents as keys in table of table extension?

Tags: netlogo

I am using the table extension as variable owned by a breed of agents.
The content of this table contains values referred to agents of another agent-set (`events`).
As table keys, I use `e-ids` a list with the `who` numbers of each agent in `events` breed. 
The following procedure initializes the tables:

```
to setup-tables
  ask walkers [
      set we-tfound table:make
      set we-interest table:make
      foreach e-ids [ [?] -> table:put we-tfound ? 0
                             table:put we-interest ? 1  ] ]
  ask links [
    set popularity table:make
    foreach e-ids [ [?] -> table:put popularity ? 0 ] ]
end
```

The answer to others posts recommends not to use `who` numbers and iterate over agents by using, for example, construct `ask agents [...]`. 
However, I do not know how could be the best way to iterate over `table:keys` using agents or someway better than whos ids.

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: You should strongly consider using links instead of tables. Instead of having an walker store a table where the keys are events, create links from walkers to events. In general, using links like this will almost always result in clearer, easier-to-maintain code than using tables. Links are a core NetLogo feature and the language makes them easy to work with; tables are not a core feature and are awkward to use.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Tables are hard to manipulate and maintain. I am afraid that my code now has grown enough and result difficult to follow. I will review the idea of using links instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since agents can't be used as keys in tables, using `who` numbers is perfectly reasonable. The danger here is that if a turtle dies, you end up with an entry that doesn't actually correspond to an existing turtle. (This is also the reason agents are not allowed as keys in tables.) You can do `is-turtle? turtle key` to see if `key` corresponds to an existing turtle.

To convert `table:keys` back to an agentset, you can do:

```
turtle-set map turtle table:keys my-table
```

Thus, to `ask` all the turtles that are keys in a table, you do:

```
ask turtle-set map turtle table:keys my-table [ do-stuff ]
```

`map turtle table:keys` converts the list of `who` numbers to a list of turtles. `turtle-set` then converts that to an agentset.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried your examples but I still have problems because tables are variables owned by e.g. `walkers` and the keys belong to another agent breed, `events`. I have tried `show turtle-set map event table:keys we-interest` but gives `ERROR: You can't use WE-INTEREST in an observer context, because WE-INTEREST is turtle-only.`

Comment: The fact that the keys are for another agent breed shouldn't be a problem. Just make sure you run that code in the context of the `walkers`. That is: `ask walkers [ show turtle-set map event table:keys we-interest ]`